# return value of NEW

Tags: c++

it it possible that in some cases `NEW` returns some value, for example NULL, or it will always throw exception?

Comment: What is `NEW`? You mean `new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.6

> Take heart. In C++, if the runtime system cannot allocate sizeof(Fred) bytes of memory during p = new Fred(), a std::bad_alloc exception will be thrown. Unlike malloc(), new never returns NULL!

[Unless your compiler "is ancient", in which case that page has a solution for you, too].

Note that if you disable exceptions in your compiler options, then you should check your compiler docs about what you can expect.

Comment: Installing a custom "new handler" can never make `new` to return 0. If that handler returns, the memory allocation will be re-attempted. The semantics in that case are well-defined and certainly not "all bets are off". Disabling exceptions is another matter though, then you have to consult the compiler's documentation...

Comment: @usta: Writing posts late at night :)  Thanks for the correction, and will fix

Answer (score 3):

`char *p = new(std::nothrow) char[1024];`

Comment: Jut one point the answer assumes std namespace is included, Otherwise need to explicitly specify std::nothrow

Answer (score 2):

A standards compliant `new` expression never evaluates to null.

You may use `std::nothrow` to return null instead of throw an exception:

```
new (std::nothrow) T();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to standard whenever `new` fails it should throw `std::bad_alloc` exception. However, you can make `new` to return NULL in case of failure using `std::nothrow`. For example: `int *p = new(std::nothrow) int;`

Answer (score 0):

`new` throws (`std::bad_alloc` if I remember well) when the allocation fails.

But you can change this behavior to mimic `malloc()` and return `NULL` instead, using `(std::nothrow)`.